# Flex/Flash Debugging in the Browser

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, flash, debugging

I'm having an issue with a Flash/Flex erroring in Firefox but not IE.  I need to see the error that the Flash/Flex app is getting from the ASP.NET app.  Is there any way to debug the response that Flash/Flex is getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Debug version of the FlashPlayer for Firefox. Maybe this is already enough and an Error might pop up.

If not use the FlexBuilder and debug the Flex application. If you don't have a license for the FlexBuilder you may also use the Evaluation licence.

Comment: See yaba's answer and just use trace in your flash or flex file. [Link](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary808.html)

Comment: The debug version helped alot, but didn't get me all the way.  I'm going to have to check ASP.NET side of things again to see if I'm missing something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can also observe the network traffic from firebug, even for flash apps.

Comment: As Joeri said, if you want to look at an error being generated FROM Firefox as opposed to from the SWF, then [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is definitely a useful tool!

Comment: unfortunately I don't see where this tool shows what the embedded plugin is doing.  The flash app uploaded a file to another resource in the background.  I need to see THAT request.  Can this do that and I'm missing it?

Comment: Normally the Net panel should show all GET and POST requests, which gives you all incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic. If it's not HTTP though, it might not be logged.

Comment: you could also have flash call javascript:console.log to have the firebug console tell you what flash is getting...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are making calls to your ASP.net app - you could use something like [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to see the url that your flex app is call and see what response is being sent back from the server (i.e. 200, 404, 503, etc...)

Also - you could use something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to do the same thing but actually see the full response from the server (be it images, text, xml...) and not just the header info.